# Youtube Analytics v2 API KEY

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

As you know there is a nearest API update for YouTube Analytics for version two and I just wanted to try it. There is a constructor of your request like a: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query

so when you fill up some fields and click on authorize and execute you will see a special formed link like a https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=insightTrafficSourceType%2Cday&endDate=2018-09-19&ids=.........&key=**{YOUR_API_KEY}**. So I can't understand which API key I need to use. Can you help me and provide a correct instruction and link to information about my issue?

Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube Analytics API uses the OAuth 2 protocol to authenticate. Basically in order to make requests you'll have to authenticate with your YouTube account. When you do so, YouTube will send back a key to the API. As mentioned in this [page of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization) you will then either be able to use this token to access the API, or you'll exchange it for another token which can be used to access the API.

OAuth 2 is somewhat involved, but you can read this article (or many others) for more about it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization

Comment: So as I understand I can't get JSON response via browser ?

Comment: I believe you can get a JSON response via the browser. In OAuth2, YouTube's server will send you information by redirecting the user to a Redirect URI that you provide to YouTube when you register your app with them. The uri will contain information for you to take. Basically the url will be something like `mysite.com/oauth/login?token=xxxxx` then your app can grab the token from the uri. Once you have the token you can make all the requests you want.